Implementing JSON Web Token (JWT) Authentication in a Java Web Application
jwt class
package com.inn.billing.com.inn.billing.JWT;

import java.util.function.Function;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
public class JwtUtil {

    private String secret = "";

    public <T> T extractClaims(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsMapper) {
        // Parse the token to obtain the Claims object
        Claims claims = parseToken(token);

        // Apply the provided function to the Claims object
        return claimsMapper.apply(claims);
    }
}

POM xml
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

While working on implementing JWT authentication in my Java web application, I encountered an issue related to importing the necessary classes and packages from the jjwt library.
i tried to decrease and increase version of the jsonwebtroken and it still couldnt import the dependencies to my project

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.

It looks like there is an issue with your maven / import settings.
Check your pom file.

You can try to generate runnable sources using Spring initializr https://start.spring.io/
Add your dependency to pom file
Don't forget to load maven changes


still does not work

Try updating your imports like this:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

Sorry for the formatting

it dosnt work in my end
